# svn: files changed from revision A compared to older revision B?

Tags: svn

How to find what files have changed in SubVersion in revision A, compared to older revision B?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question fully, but svn diff -r<rev-1>:<rev> --summarize will give you the files changed for a particular commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listing commit comment and file actions:

```
svn log -r B:A -v
```

Listing differences:

```
svn di -r B:A
```

Listing just changed files:

```
svn di -r B:A --summarize
```

Comment: Thanks, `--summarize` is what I've been looking for.